# android imageview onClick animation

Tags: android, animation, onclick, imageview

I guess this is kind of an odd question but I have tried setting onClicklistener on an ImageView and it has worked. But the problem is that the user cannot sense the click. I mean if some of u have worked on other mobile environs(like Apple iPhone) then when we click on an Image in other environs then it gives an effect on the image so that the user can understand that the image has been clicked.

I have tried setting alpha using `setalpha` method but it doesn't work. Though the same thing is working fine on onFocusListener implementation. Can some1 suggest a different way to modify the image on click...

I am new to android so haven't learnt the nuances of simple animation also... if there is any simple animation I can use for the same then please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using AppCompat theme, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388361/1770409

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<alpha
android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
android:toAlpha = "0.5"
android:duration = "300">
</alpha>
<scale
android:fromXScale = "1"
android:toXScale = "0.9" 
android:fromYScale = "1"
android:toYScale = "0.9" 
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" 
android:duration = "50">
</scale>
</set>
```

I don't know if this is the correct method but defining an animation as mentioned did the trick. Now we just have to give

```
public void onClick(View v) {
v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context, R.anim.image_click));
//Your other coding if present
}
```

in the OnClick method and the change will be visible...

Comment: ya.. all thanx to u and others who shared their ideas... hope the method i posted will be useful for some1 else too...

Comment: What an awesome effect! I was looking for a black click effect and when i tested this I was surprised! Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you very much... found this post accidentally though !!

Comment: but it starts animating after click.. it should behave like.. #1st shrink on touch #2nd become normal when you release press..

Comment: super effect! Thanks a lot for sharing that code! Awesome!

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to use a drawable that contains different images for the different states you want to support.  Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_at_rest" />
</selector>
```

Name this file img.xml or something and put it in your drawable directory, then set your ImageView's image to img.xml.  `@drawable/img_at_rest` is the original image you're trying to use, while `@drawable/img_pressed` and `@drawable/img_focused` are the images to use for their respective states.  You can also use solid colors instead of images if it's appropriate for your use case.

Comment: wow... this is something which i can use... but can i just tweek the code so that the image doesnt change but the alpha of the image is changed???

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  The xml interfaces for the android.graphics.drawable package are not well documented.  See if you can find a way to specify an alpha transparency, or perhaps nest an alpha color over your image within an <item> specification.

Comment: well Mike my problem is that the image is not from resource but from the internet... hence changing images i guess wont help... Thanx 4 such a quick response...

Answer (score 2):

anim/anim_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1."
    android:duration="1000">
  </alpha>
</set>
```

And add:

```
myView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_item));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but have you tried setSelected()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setSelected(boolean)