# How to make a circular ripple on a button when it's being clicked?

Tags: android, button, rippledrawable

### Background

On the dialer app of Android, when you start searching for something, and you click the arrow button on the left of the EditText, you get a circular ripple effect on it :

[image]

### The problem

I've tried to have it too, but I got a rectangular one:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/navButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/search_ic_back_arrow"/>
```

### The question

How do I make the button have a circular ripple effect when being clicked? Do I have to create a new drawable, or is there a built in way for that?

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect  try this

Comment: possible answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477025/how-to-set-a-ripple-effect-on-textview-or-imageview-on-android

Comment: Consider changing your selected answer to the one with the most upvotes, as it actually solves the problem

Comment: @JeffBarger Why? Both work fine. There is no better one between them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you already have a background image, here is an example of a ripple that looks close to selectableItemBackgroundBorderless:

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_show_filter_dialog"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_state"/>
```

ic_filter_state.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_pressed_ripple"/>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_filter" />
</selector>
```

state_pressed_ripple.xml: (opacity set to 10% on white background) 1AFFFFFF

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#1AFFFFFF"/>
            </shape>
            <color android:color="#FFF"/>
        </item>
    </ripple>
```

Comment: What happened if it is a layer list?

Answer (score 357):

If you are using AppCompat theme, then you could set the background of the view as:

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

This will add circular ripple on 21 and above and square background on below 21.

Comment: Nice. Can I also set the color of it somehow?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you might want to create your own custom style for it using ripple for v21+

Comment: So I guess tinting won't help?

Comment: in API 23 the 'up' background appears to be half the size in comparison to selectbleItemBackgroundBorderless

Comment: @androiddeveloper, color can be set by setting colorControlHighlight like below in your styles.xml

     <item name="colorControlHighlight">#F00</item>

Comment: Above is the answer to show ripple, my previous comment was for setting different ripple color than the default color.

Comment: how to set it in java? android.R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless didn't work

Comment: @bond how can i make this same effect with custom colors

Comment: If you are using it inside other layouts, you might need `android:clipChildren="false"` in the layouts as well to allow the animation to propagate.

Comment: @AbduazizKayumov It depends how you try it. Use something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27020758/878126

Comment: this solution is great for static images. However, I'm using an AppCompatImageView with frame-animation and the background is used for the animation, so this lovely one-liner doesn't work with that. I've tried `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` and it gives a ripple, however, the ripple effect reveals a square - which is ugly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked on imageview with circular src drawable

Comment: It's not circular with ImageView in Android 9. Its square

Comment: It is not working with the new MaterialComponents theme. `Theme.MaterialComponents`

Comment: If the ripple effect is not showing in dark mode then try adding `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` in your view

Answer (score 126):

Another attribute with round ripple effect, specially for action bar:

```
android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
```

**UPD**: Ripple color can be changed by this attribute:

```
<!--somewhere in styles-->
<item name="colorControlHighlight">your_color_here</item>
```

But keep in mind, this attribute applies to all default ripple effects.

Comment: Any way to customize it? For example the color? Maybe something in styles? Or even more specifically in the view XML tag itself?

Comment: I do not know, today I solved this problem and the answers above did not work as I needed. I assume that the color can be customized in styles, but definitely not in the view.

Comment: If you figure it out, please let me know. Could be useful.

Comment: This is exactly the right effect I'm looking for. By the way, can you mention where to find this attribute, it seems not be documented.

Comment: @JackWang it is in  "?attr/actionBarItemBackground"

Comment: @MeysamHadigheh `?` is shortcut for `?attr/`

Answer (score 56):

Create and set a ripple drawable as background. Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/grey_15">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
        <color android:color="@color/white"/>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: It's something in my code. You can use your colors :)

Comment: How would I use the default selector in case it's on pre-Lollipop ? Also, does it use the same colors as the one on the dialer?

Comment: You can put the ripple drawable in your drawables-v21 folder. And for pre L use a simple state drawable. Use the same file name and put it into the drawable (default) folder.

Comment: I mean, what should it have for pre-Lollipop, inside its drawable file? Also, please answer about the color. Is it possible to use the same one that's used for "selectableItemBackground" ?

Comment: Ripple is not available in pre-lollipop. So in the drawable file of pre-lollipop, ordinary button drawable is needed. <item name="state_pressed" color=" ....   . . "

Comment: You can also create a style. In values-v21 folder create a new style and set the ripple drawable as background. And for pre L, i.e. in your values folder styles.xml put as background the "selectableItemBackground" attribute for the same style.

Comment: @ThomasR. Can you please show exactly what to put? Also, what's the value of "grey_15" ?

Comment: According to my tests, this works only if the button has a square shape (width==height). when it's not, I get an elliptic shape. I've even tried to set the size of the drawable with equal width and height, but I still get this issue. How come?

Comment: <ripple> require api level 21 :)

Comment: If you want the same ripple color as the other default ripple effects used in the app, use "?attr/colorControlHighlight" as the color.

Comment: I recommend to change the shape from oval to rectangle and then within the shape add something like <corners android:radius="8dp" />

Answer (score 45):

### Just Add this background to your view

`"android:background=?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"`

Answer (score 22):

You can create circle ripple drawable using `android:radius` attribute in xml.

Example:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="your_color"
    android:radius="your_radius" />
```

Pay attention, that your `your_radius` should be less then your view width and height. 
For example: if you have view  with size `60dp x 60dp` `your_radius` should be near `30dp` (width / 2 or height / 2).

> Work on Android 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 9):

**update 2021:**

you need use **actionBarItemBackground** for **background**

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

Example:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_copy" />
```

Answer (score 7):

just add this item in your activity xml

```
           <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />
```

Comment: Seems identical to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54440773/878126 .

Answer (score 3):

If you want more generic XML files, I have two files:

1) **btn_ripple_background** with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_circular_shape"/>
</selector>
```

2) **ripple_circuler_shape** with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/btn_state_pressed_text_color"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/btn_state_pressed_text_color" />
</shape>
```

finally the usage:`android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_btn_background"`

Answer (score 3):

If you want ripple effect which will not cross the circle boundary, you can check this code. It works for me perfecrly. Just remember, you have to give id=@android:id/mask in ripple_blue.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/send_password_to_mail_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_blue"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />
```

`ripple_blue.xml`

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorRipple">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWindowBackground"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWindowBackground"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

</ripple>
```

`color.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <color name="colorWindowBackground">#F2F5FC</color>
    <color name="colorRipple">#0288d1</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?actionBarItemBackground"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Smoother than setting actionBarItemBackground as background. But still not exactly same as action bar animation itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also fixed this problem in one of my projects. `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` is responsible for the ripple effect, that's why it is set in the foreground and `android:clipToPadding="false"` will prevent the ripple effect cut off and make it rectangular.It will keep your ripple effect circular.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/navButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:src="@drawable/search_ic_back_arrow"/>
```

Comment: Not sure if you can put comments inside this way, and even then, you probably wanted to put each above. In addition, doesn't using `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` mean it will be quite large for the case I've show (in a small area) ? Anyway, how do you change the color of the ripple this way?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin / Java you can do the following

```kotlin
fun View.applyCircularRippleEffect() {
    val backgroundResId = context.getResource(android.R.attr.actionBarItemBackground)

    if (backgroundResId != 0) {
        setBackgroundResource(backgroundResId)
        isClickable = true
        isFocusable = true
    }
}

// getResource extension
fun Context.getResource(resourceId: Int): Int {
    val out = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(resourceId, out, true)

    return out.resourceId
}
```

Comment: context.getResource not found

Comment: @RahulMandaliya thank you for the comment. My bad, it was my custom extension method. Added it to the answer