# How to set a ripple effect on textview or imageview on Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, material-design

I want to set a ripple effect on textview and imageview in Android Studio. How can I do it?

Comment: Please elaborate your question first.What actually you need and what have you tried so far.Simply saying that i want ripple effect makes it a very broad question.You can also give some link for reference as to what you want.Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually i want effect for text-view and image-view select/unselect effect.

Comment: have you tried searching for the same?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Ref : http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html,

http://wiki.workassis.com/category/android/android-xml/

```
<TextView
.
.
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
/>

<ImageView
.
.
.
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Comment: nice its worked with me on lollipop,but this way for which android android version? and does it work on pre-lollipop?

Comment: If you set a click listener on the TextView, you do not need to add android:clickable="true" to the view in the xml file.

Comment: @Richard I've had an issue with KitKat (or ICS) a year ago, and click listeners didn't work without android:clickable="true" for that version

Comment: On modern versions of android, this is now `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: How can use this when I want a custom background ??

Comment: The difference between this with/without `Borderless` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOjA8tS5sbc

Comment: `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` shows a circle regardless of the view's size, and `selectableItemBackground` shows a grey ripple confined in the view's size (in my case, square).

Comment: How do I change the ripple color?

Comment: Thank you for this! btw if you want to use your own custom image use       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location"

Comment: Also, should be added `android:focusable="true"`.

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI  What if we already have a background? How can we do it then?

Comment: @MohammadZarei then use foreground ripple effect with the background.

Answer (score 106):

If you want the ripple to be bounded to the size of the TextView/ImageView use:

```
<TextView
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"/>
```

(I think it looks better)

Comment: Is there any difference in using ```selectableItemBackground``` vs ```selectableItemBackgroundBorderless```

Comment: I don't know why it was not bounded to borders and it expand through whole layout

Comment: @rakeshkashyap the difference is that selectableItemBackground will keep the ripple within it's view size(width/height). selectableItemBackgroundBorderless will expand it's ripple over other views (like the official calculator app ripple)

Comment: and also need to set this >>> android:focusable="true"

Answer (score 44):

Please refer below answer for ripple effect.

ripple on Textview or view :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

ripple on Button or Imageview :

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: Please notice that `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` is API 21+. Below you can choose `selectableItemBackground` to avoid compatibility issue

Comment: Thanks! It has effect on API 23+. Also instead you can use `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` and `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. I think, `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` are optional.

Answer (score 19):

Add
`android:clickable="true"`
`android:focusable="true"`

For Ripple Effect

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

For Selectable Effect

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For Button effect

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 13):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="@string/banner"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Add this into drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--this ripple animation only working for >= android version 21 -->

<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/click_efect" />
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [android-ripple-background](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background)

**Start Effect**

```
final RippleBackground rippleBackground=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.content);
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.centerImage);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
    }
});
```

**Stop animation:**

```
rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation();
```

For KOTLIN

```
val rippleBackground = findViewById(R.id.content) as RippleBackground
val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.centerImage) as ImageView
imageView.setOnClickListener(object : OnClickListener() {
    fun onClick(view: View?) {
        rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation()
    }
})
```

Comment: nice! is there a Kotlin version of this?

Comment: @rengineer yes. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 9):

for circle ripple : 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

for rectangle ripple : 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Answer (score 8):

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 6):

In the case of the well voted solution posted by @Bikesh M Annur ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128965/4744263)) doesn't work to you, try using:

```
<TextView
...
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true" />

<ImageView
...
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true" />
```

Also, when using `android:clickable="true"` add `android:focusable="true"` because:

"*A widget that is declared to be clickable but not declared to be focusable is not accessible via the keyboard.*"

Answer (score 4):

addition to above answers is adding focusable to avoid UI editor's warning

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

If above solutions are not working for your **TextView** then this will definitely work:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_8dp"
        android:text="Clickable Text"
        android:textColor="your text color"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rippleColor="ripple effect color" />
```

Here, `style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` and `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"` will make this button as transparent background so that it will look like TextView and everything else will be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Bikesh M Annur's answer, be sure to update your support libraries. Previously I was using 23.1.1 and nothing happened. Updating it to 23.3.0 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The best way its add:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBack"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_black"
        android:tint="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/textHint"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>




<TextView
      android:id="@+id/t9_key_6"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="@string/number_six"
      android:background="@drawable/keyboard_button_bg"
      android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

selectableItemBackgroundBorderless does not work when you have some background or background color property set. It wasn't working for me.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

but the good news is that it works on the foreground as well.

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score -5):

Using libraries. [This](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) is one of them. Just add its dependency and put below code in xml before each elements that needs ripple effect:

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
android:id="@+id/ripple"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: oh please no, it's not the best way because you have less control over it and it's widely supported in the Android SDK itself. If anyone reads this I recommend to either look at the comment of @Bikesh or Karthik if you want to control the color.