# Building UI/layout for a table-like list where cells are buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-tablelayout

I'm new to Android development, and would like some input on a UI problem. I need a list of things, each of which is numbered (up to ~20 items), and each having 1-4 "subitems", kind of like shown in the sketch (except properly aligned). The number is supposed to act as a big button, and the subitem portion to the right is supposed to act as another large button (the two clickable areas for each row are shown with red boxes). My question then, is, what would be the ideal, most android-y way of building a such interface?

[image: rough layout]

I currently have a very simple demo working, built with TableLayout inside a ScrollView, where each TableRow is two columns wide (the first cell containing the number in a single TextView, and the second containing LinearLayout of TextViews, one for each subitem); however, I have a couple of issues:

- Only the TextViews (not the surrounding padding) are clickable; I would like the entire red box to be clickable, but only the green box actually is
- There are no click animations
- I haven't even tried making the subitem area clickable yet, but it seems to me that I would at very least need to make each subitem (TextView) clickable (which would entail adding the click handler to each subitem separately), and that even then I would have the problem of only strictly the TextView itself being clickable, not the whole cell

Some options I have thought of:

- Use flat buttons instead of TextViews for the numbers on the left; that would take care of the animation/feedback side, but I'm not sure if this would fix the problem of the padding not being clickable, or how it would work in the subitem column
- Use a ListView instead of TableLayout; I don't know what kind of dark magic I would need to make all the buttons on the left the same size / align the subitem lists, and I still wouldn't know how to make the number large enough so that the user won't accidentally miss it
- Some other proper solution that I haven't thought of yet, that doesn't involve any shoehorning and ugly workarounds

What to do? Is my current approach already sound, just in need of some easy tweaks that I don't know of yet?

Comment: you can refer to this if you only want to add animation in textViews http://stackoverflow.com/a/34128965/6171845

Answer (score 1):

You can add button programmatically on your demand like this

```
public void AddAll() {
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
    rl.addView(btn); 
    btn.setText("Button");

    btn.setWidth(320);
    btn.setHeight(40);
}

}
```