# How to set ripple effect only on image button of TableRow item android

Tags: android, colors, imagebutton

I want to add custom ripple effect on image button. But if I change background , it shows color effect behind the image. Also, I set table-row and image-button wrap content but still couldn't find solution.
Please help me to set ripple effect only on image button not outside space.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ess_btn_leave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/leave"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ess_imgbtn_expence"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/expence"
        />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: what is tagetversion?

Comment: tergetversion- 25

Comment: You should have `width` or `height` = "0dp" as per orientation due to use of `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on your image view.
for default ripple

for custom ripple you need to create two files
In your drawable-v21 create a file - `background_ripple.xml`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
android:color="@color/lightGrey" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

in your normal drawable for version above 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/lightGrey" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/white" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

and do `android:foreground="@drawable/background_ripple.xml` on your image view.

Answer (score 0):

Add this .xml to your drawable folder

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</ripple>
```

and use this as a background to your imageButton for ripple effect.

Comment: i tried this way as well. but it covers left and right side spaces around imagebutton and effect performs behind the imageButton

Comment: @ShuchiSheth then How you want ripple effect is should be cover entire imageButton?

Comment: i have given 0.5 weight to my imagebutton. i have set image scaletype as fitcenter. so on click of image ,it  shows effect on whole layout. i want it only on imagebutton

Comment: @ShuchiSheth instead of android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" try android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html
and the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128965/4407321)

Try

```
<ImageView
.
.
.
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_button"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
/>
```

Comment: thank you. but i want to add custom ripple effect. how to set that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml

Comment: post your expected output screen shot so that it will easy to get it

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:-

In parent Layout of `xml` add below line:-

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

In ImageButton set-

```
android:background="@drawable/grid_ripple_effect"
```

> **`grid_ripple_effect.xml`** in that change color as per your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/light_green"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:left="-2dp"  android:right="-2dp" android:top="-2dp">
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/light_green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```