# Android background default when pressed object

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to customize my textview when pressed will look like this
how to do that ?

[image: how to do it ?]

Comment: in your image it's not a `textview` it's a `recyclerview`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27006288/7409774

Comment: @Peter So you need to implement ripple effect on textview ...

Comment: use **ripple effect** ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a ripple effect on textview or imageview on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477025/how-to-set-a-ripple-effect-on-textview-or-imageview-on-android)

Comment: see this http://www.tothenew.com/blog/ripple-effect-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `ripple_effect.xml` file and add following code. `res/drawable/ripple_effect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

see the link : http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/how-to-add-ripple-effect-to-android-button.html   implement it in your code where you want to add effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="yourcolorcode">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```